# moodle webservice api how to get data and pass parameters to the url

Tags: ios, api, moodle

I'm trying to connect Moodle with my IOS Application , but i dont understand how i can use web service api for moodle , for example

> user  core_user_get_users_by_id() moodle_user_get_users_by_id()   2.0 Get
>   users by id

this function from moodle documentations as i understand the url must be like this

http://xxxxx.com/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=mytoken&wsfunction=core_user_get_users_by_id&&usersid=33&moodlewsrestformat=json

is that correct ? for your knowledge already i know how to get token , and it's work . but i want to know , how to get my assignments  also get my subjects , subjects ID , the submissions  date of the assignment  and many other information which it's very important  .

already i have checked this

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_services_Roadmap

some of functions which dose not need parameters it's worked fine , but other , i got error invalid  parameters

please help me .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't, you will want to check out the webservices api documentation for moodle by going to "site administration>plugins>web services>api documentation" on your moodle site.

Comparing your URL with the documentation, I believe you will need to change it to:

http://xxxxx.com/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=mytoken&wsfunction=core_user_get_users_by_id&userids[0]=33&moodlewsrestformat=json

If you wanted multiple users (assuming you want users with id 34 and 35):

http://xxxxx.com/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=mytoken&wsfunction=core_user_get_users_by_id&userids[0]=33&userids[1]=34&userids[2]=35&moodlewsrestformat=json

On a side note, this function is being deprecated, so you may want to investigate core_user_get_users_by_field